# UK visit visa to get married rejected

Tags: visas, uk, ireland

I am a Moroccan. I met a British woman in 2013 and we decided to get married. We thought everything would be easy. She started working in a shop for 8 pounds per hour.

Then I applied for a UK visit visa so that we could get married. We had already made an appointment for the marriage at the UK Registry Office. My visa was rejected, although I have a good job and good savings.

We have a daughter who is now 2 years old and I have seen her only two or three times. She doesn't really know me, although we sometimes talk via Skype. I also applied for a visitor visa to go see her and that, too, was rejected. My British girlfriend is pregnant again with our second daughter and I'll be in same situation as with my first daughter.

I'm going to try to apply to Ireland for a visitor visa and, because there is no border from there to the UK, perhaps I will get it and be able to see my second daughter when she born.

I have received Schengen visas four times without any problems so that I've been able to visit with my girlfriend and daughter.

Comment: I removed your email address. We might be able to help if you scan and redact and upload a copy of your refusal notice. See http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-do-i-upload-an-image for help.

Comment: "now im gonna try my chance to aply for visa ireland visitor visa and because there is no borders maybe i will get it and go see my second daughter when she born" - as far as I know, Irish visa does not give you permission to visit UK - British-Irish visa scheme is only for Chinese and Indian citizens.

Comment: @GeorgeY. As I read it, the OP contemplates using the CTA loophole, but his question is scoped to an ROI visit application following a UK MVV refusal. So that would be on topic if we had the relevant notice. Close voting as 'unclear'.

Comment: Probably they suspect you are trying to gain permanent residency under the guise of a visit visa. But as @GayotFow mentioned put your refusal notice to get an answer.

Comment: If you want to live together as a family I expect your best strategy is for your girlfriend to move to continental Europe and marry you. She should then be able to get you a residence permit as a family member of an EU citizen. If you are going to do this I would suggest doing so ASAP as brexit may close this option down.